# Confused about $0 in Dictionary.reduce()

Tags: swift, swift3

Im trying to sum the total value of a stock, the right answer is:

```
let stock = [1.5:5, 10:2, 4.99:20, 2.30:5, 8.19:30]
let stockSum = stock.reduce(0, { 
    $0 + $1.key * Double($1.value)
})
```

But my conception is:

```
...
let stockSum = stock.reduce(0, { 
    $0.key * Double($0.value) + $1.key * Double($1.value)
})
```

Definitely it returns an error, anyone can help me to explain it?

Comment: $0 represents the partial amount summed up. There is no key value properties. $1 represents your dictionary

Comment: Your code could also be written as `let stockSum = stock.reduce(0) { total, dic in
    total + dic.key * Double(dic.value)
}` so you can better understand whats going on there.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the parameter list for the `reduce` method

```
reduce(initialResult: Result, nextPartialResult: (Result, (key: Double, value: Int)) throws -> Result)
```

In your case, `0` is assigned to `initialResult` which essentially saves the sum up to a certain point while iterating. This `initialResult` is passed in as the first parameter in `$0` and the dictionaries' key,value is passed as the second parameter in `$1`. Hence you see `$1.key` and `$1.value`